# ffmpeg + Raspberry Pi 4b + stream_loop CPU optimization

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I'm making a Pi livestreaming covid tracker, but watching my CPU/RAM get decimated

```
VBR="2500k"
FPS="30"
QUAL="medium"
YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
KEY="..."
TEXTFILE="message.txt"

ffmpeg \
    -re -stream_loop -1 \
    -i a.mp4 \
    -vf "drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=30: \
    fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:textfile=$TEXTFILE:reload=1" \
    -vcodec libx264 -preset $QUAL -r $FPS \
    -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
```

When I run that, top gives me `%CPU 282` `%MEM 4.0`

I installed ffmpeg with `sudo apt-get ffmpeg`

I'm not sure if I'm using hardware acceleration.  It was brought up in a number of posts that were a year old or so.

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: ah i'm running it with `h264_omx` now and it's down to `CPU 54` `MEM 1.2`.  Cool!  Though getting a few warnings here's my output: https://gist.github.com/beamercola/3991d5fd2c9cd2b02a3a29c5735f6c7d

Comment: I was going to suggest omx (OpenMAX) if your ffmpeg supported it. You can make that the answer to your question. The message means it is ignoring `-preset` because `h264_omx` doesn't support that option. No need to change the frame rate, so omit `-r`. Consider trying to stream copy the AAC audio instead of re-encoding it to MP3: `-c:a copy`. May want to manully set GOP for streaming (frame rate x2) = `-g 60`. You should change your stream key now by the way. Decoding via MMAL may help some. Guessing it's `-c:v h264_mmal` but I didn't look.

Comment: `-c:v h264_mmal` is to be used as an input option (before `-i`), assuming I got the name right.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful to me, thank you. humming along now.  `h264_mmal` seems like it's supported but i need to compile ffmpeg manually.  How low on CPU/Memory should I be shooting for?  is 30% an option? (running multiple streams on a single device would be great)

Comment: Your ffmpeg already has `--enable-mmal` so you probably don't need to compile. Not sure about the cpu/memory question.